# how to clean Laravel Bootstrap cache config file?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I developed laravel app locally and uploaded in shared hosting.

While hosting I changed the database name and username of mysql in the .env and the config/database files.

But in remote its still using the old db name and user which is found in the bootstrap/cache/config file.

So how to clean the bootstrap/cache/config.php file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `php artisan cache:clear` to flush the application's cache.

Answer (score 60):

If you are trying to clear configuration cache, which it sounds like you are. You need to run:

`php artisan config:clear`

At some point, you probably ran `php artisan config:cache` which generated a cached version of your config file, and this file is **not** cleared with `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 36):

I tried all the above options but nothing works.

I manually removed from bootstrap/cache/config.php. And it works. This is the **Ultimate** solution.

Answer (score 28):

I just stumbled into this while building automated deployment in AWS. The problem with Laravel is that artisan commands also use the cache. Now if you deploy the new version of your application you may have outdated entries in the cache which in turn will make the artisan command crash i.e. cannot find some class that was cached but no longer exist. Therefore you either need to:

1. Clear cache before you deploy the application

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

2. Clear cache manually

```
rm -rf bootstrap/cache/*.php
```

Finally you want to run optimize command which will re-build your configuration cache, bootstrap file cache and route caches.

```
php artisan optimize
```

Answer (score 5):

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Or you can just manually delete **bootstrap/config.php**, which is what artisan does after all.

See: vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConfigClearCommand.php

Answer (score 5):

Here is the Tip,

1. Flushing Application cache

   - Use `php artisan cache:clear` to flush the application cache or `php artisan cache:forget` to discard specific cache.
   - You can use `php artisan config:clear` to clear cached configuration of application.
2. Removing Blade Templates cache

   You can use `php artisan view:clear` to clear all compiled views.
3. Application Bootstrap cache

   If you want to clear the application bootstraper cache, `php artisan optimize:clear` will help you.
4. Route Cache

   There also a command to clear the route cache as `php artisan route:clear`.
5. Events and Listeners cache

   For events and listeners cache you can use `php artisan event:clear`

if you still stuck in finding helpful commands, you can run `php artisan list` and it will list out every command with its description. look for a specific thing you want to perform. if you need migration-related command, you can look in `migration`.

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me was to remove the files in the `bootstrap/cache/` directory and then delete the `vendor` folder. Re-run `composer install` and then `composer dump-autoload` and the above campaigns should run fine. Deleting the `vendor` folder and re-running `composer install` was the missing link for me

Comment: This did not work for me.  My config file is gone in bootstrap and I'm sill getting the error.  I don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

Laravel 4 : `php artisan cache:clear`

also for laravel 5(not tested),

`Illuminate\Cache\FileStore` has the function `flush`

```
Cache::flush();
```

also,

```
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider as DoctrineCache;

DoctrineCache::flushAll();
```

Comment: For laravel 5. where do i run this command from. Shall i create a closure in routes.php and run from there

Comment: php artisan cache:clear has to be executed from command prompt. You will have to navigate to your root folder of project, to execute it. For laravel 5, it is argued that one does not need to clear the cache. Yet if you wanna try, use it in controller.