# Laravel bootstrap cache

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I have something messed up in project. At first I didn't have debug mode even when I edited `app.php` to set `APP_DEBUG` to true. I would just get the error message that something went wrong, and that's where it ended. I could see errors in `laravel.log` though.

After reading lots of different solutions and trying everything from deleting cache, changing permissions on storage...nothing worked. But I noticed something strange. Log error was saying that certain view couldn't be found inside bootstrap's `compile.php`. The view is under Laravel's native `views` folder. Deleting or regenerating `compile.php` didn't help also. But under `bootstrap -> cache` folder there is also `config.php`. There I could change debug mode also, and strangely enough, and that change actually reflects, and I can see debug messages?

Everything seems to look up to bootstrap folder for references instead the real places...what seems to be the issue?

Comment: This may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729543/how-to-stop-laravel-5-from-caching-configurations

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823207/how-to-clean-laravel-bootstrap-cache-config-file

Comment: `config:clear` did the trick...I was trying with cache only. Thanks

Comment: In that case, feel free to self-answer so that others may find this useful.